# Plots not showing when calling matplotlib from r block in rmarkdown

Tags: python, matplotlib, r-markdown

I have the following function to plot some matrices using python:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_freq_bin_mats(subject, freq_bins):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    for i, f in enumerate(freq_bins, start=1):
        subj_file = base_dir + subject + '_' + f + '.txt'
        print(subj_file)
        if os.path.exists(subj_file):
            freq_mat = np.loadtxt(subj_file, delimiter=',')
        else:
            freq_mat = np.zeros((46,46))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(3,4,i)
        ax.set_title("{0}".format(f))
        ax.spy(freq_mat, markersize=1, color='black')
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_xticks([])
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.suptitle("{0}".format(subject), fontsize=14, y=1)
    plt.show()
```

I am trying to use this code from an R block in an Rmarkdown document so I can take advantage of `par(mfrow)` to create a grid layout from a for loop. However, when I run the python source code from an R block, no plot is shown. I get no error messages. the following is the code I am attempting to use:

```
source_python('/path/to/script.py')
plot_freq_bin_mats(py$all_subjects[1], py$freq_bins)
```

And here is my Rmarkdown setup:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::knit_engines$set(python=reticulate::eng_python)
library(reticulate)
use_python('/opt/anaconda3/bin/python')
matplotlib <- import("matplotlib")
matplotlib$use("Agg", force = TRUE)
```

I've tried it both with and without the final line but neither work. Is there a way to show matplotlib plots from an R code block in Rmarkdown?